# Rendering a video in shiny UI

Tags: r, video, shiny

I have a very simple question. Is it possible to render a short video clip in a shiny UI?

The idea is to have an UI similiar to this one

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Welcome to the Experiment"),
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("runButton", "Roll the dice"),
    helpText("You have x draws"),
    helpText("Your Draw"), 
    uiOutput('test',align="center")

  ),
  mainPanel(
    helpText("Your draw"),
    tableOutput("first"),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    img(src='dice1.png', align = "right"),
    helpText("Your redemption Coupon Code is"),
    tableOutput("second")

  )
)
)
```

But i want to place a video file inside the 'test' object .

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Use the package called `'shinyLP'`

Then use the below codes in your `ui.r`

```
iframe(width = "250", height = "150",url_link="www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to upload a video as a file, but embedding a YouTube video is fairly straightforward using HTML code:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Welcome to the Experiment"),
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("runButton", "Roll the dice"),
    helpText("You have x draws"),
    helpText("Your Draw"), 
    HTML('<iframe width="200" height="100" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')

  ),
  mainPanel(
    helpText("Your draw"),
    tableOutput("first"),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    img(src='dice1.png', align = "right"),
    helpText("Your redemption Coupon Code is"),
    tableOutput("second")

  )
)
)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this code. But the video is not loading when i run the app.

Comment: I tried the above again, works for me with a server.R of: shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {}) Do you have any other code surrounding? Maybe try with another video link?